# styled components override parent props types

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = styled.div<{url: string}>`
//some css
`
```

And I have a child component

```
const ChildComponent = styled(ParentComponent)`
//some css
`
```

So in the child component `url` is required, is it possible to override the type for a child? So that I don't need to pass url to the child. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. The only way I can think of is to supply the required url in the attrs so you don't need to set the url every time you use the `ChildComponent`

```js
const ChildComponent = styled(ParentComponent).attrs({ url: null })`
  //some css
`;
```